# how to remove a parameter from url on page refresh php

Tags: php

I am sending error values in the url.For example if i have a website named

```
www.example.com
```

and the url for login page is

```
www.example.com/login.php.
```

If the user enters wrong credentials url will be

```
www.example.com/login.php?invalid.
```

So everytime i refresh url remains

```
www.example.com/login.php?invalid.
```

How to remove **invalid** from url on refresh???

Comment: Why do you required `invalid` parameter in url?

Comment: I will be displaying error message when the url contains invalid.

Comment: Then it's better to use `session` or `jquery`.

Comment: if i dont want to use session and use jquery, is there any example or suggestion??

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Why would you refresh the login.php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that by using the `invalid` GET variable you try to determine whether or not to display the error message to the user. This isn't really a good way to do so, due to the number of reasons, one of which made you ask this question.

You have a number of options instead, one of which would be using the session variables to store the error message. E.g., if the user login fails, you could store the message in your session:

```
if (badLogin()) {
    $_SESSION['errorMessage'] = "Something's wrong";
}
```

and then on the login.php page you could try and see if it exists:

```
// ...your HTML...
if (!empty($_SESSION['errorMessage'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['errorMessage']; // show it to the user
    unset($_SESSION['errorMessage']); // so as not to display it every time
}
// ...your HTML continues...
```

This is not the perfect way either, but without knowing your application structure it's hard to suggest anything else.

Comment: Ok i will try it this way